# Conditionally overwriting a list using the purrr package in R?

Tags: r, purrr

Say I have the dataset below. It contains the non-centrality parameter (NCP), the degrees of freedom (DF), and the number of simulations (10,000) for each party's candidate in three states. As you can see, some races don't have candidates for a given party:

```
dat <- tibble(state = c("Iowa", "Wisconsin", "Minnesota"), 
              ncp_D = c(0, 11000, 5700),
              ncp_R = c(10000, 12000, 5000), 
              ncp_Ind = c(1800, 0, 600),
              df_D = c(10),
              df_R = c(10),
              df_Ind = c(10),
              sims_D = c(10000),
              sims_R = c(10000),
              sims_Ind = c(10000))
```

I would like the code to produce 10,000 simulations for each candidate in the three states using the `purrr` package. Below is the code I use to initiate this process based off of the t-distribution (`rt()`):

```
dat_results <- dat %>% 
  mutate(DVotes = pmap(list(sims_D, df_D, ncp_D), rt),
         RVotes = pmap(list(sims_R, df_R, ncp_R), rt),
         IndVotes = pmap(list(sims_Ind, df_Ind, ncp_Ind), rt))
```

This produces three lists of vote possibilities in the `dat_results` dataframe, but I ultimately want the lists that are produced for a candidate to be full of zeroes if their ncp value is zero. For instance, the D candidate in Iowa should have their predicted values based off the `rt()` function to be 10,000 zeroes instead of values that use 0 as its NCP, thus yielding some negative values. Same with the Ind candidate in Wisconsin. Essentially I'm trying to *conditionally overwrite a list* in a dataframe.

Is there an easy way to do this in R, preferably using the `purrr` package? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think the easiest is to change the `rt()` function:

```
cond_rt <- function(n, df, ncp, ...){
  if(ncp == 0) return(rep(0, n))
  rt(n, df, ncp, ...)
}
```

Then simply use that modified version:

```
dat_results <- dat %>% 
  mutate(DVotes = pmap(list(sims_D, df_D, ncp_D), cond_rt),
         RVotes = pmap(list(sims_R, df_R, ncp_R), cond_rt),
         IndVotes = pmap(list(sims_Ind, df_Ind, ncp_Ind), cond_rt))

map_dbl(dat_results$DVotes, length)
#> [1] 10000 10000 10000
map_dbl(dat_results$DVotes, sum)
#> [1]         0 119262980  61756273
```

But if you really wanted to conditionally modify a column *a posteriori*, that could be done with `mutate()` and `if_else()`. We just run into a problem as we need to read and write list-elements, this can be solved with `rowwise()` (to read a single row element at a time) and calling `list()` on the output, so that we obtain a list of length 1 that can be inserted as an element.

```
dat_results2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(DVotes = pmap(list(sims_D, df_D, ncp_D), rt),
         RVotes = pmap(list(sims_R, df_R, ncp_R), rt),
         IndVotes = pmap(list(sims_Ind, df_Ind, ncp_Ind), rt)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(DVotes = if_else(ncp_D == 0, list(rep(0, length(DVotes))), list(DVotes)),
         RVotes = if_else(ncp_R == 0, list(rep(0, length(RVotes))), list(RVotes)),
         IndVotes = if_else(ncp_Ind == 0, list(rep(0, length(IndVotes))), list(IndVotes)))

map_dbl(dat_results2$DVotes, length)
#> [1] 10000 10000 10000
map_dbl(dat_results2$DVotes, sum)
#> [1]         0 119172966  61629269
```

This could probably be simplified with `across()`.

Comment: Thanks for this, @Alexlok. Quick question: Say I want the cond_rt function to only return non-negative values. (That is, any negative values returned by the function are converted to zero.) Right now if the NCP is just above zero the function will return negative values since it's following the rules of the t-distribution. Do you have a suggestion for how to implement that in the function's logic? Thanks again.

Comment: Simple thresholding should work: `x <- rt(...); x[x<0] <- 0`. But the resulting distribution is not anymore a proper non-central t distribution, so I don't whether the analysis would still be correct.